# Class method takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have read several topics with similar problem, but I don't understand the error is thrown in my case.

I have a class method:

```
def submit_new_account_form(self, **credentials):
...
```

When I call it on an instance of my object like this:

```
create_new_account = loginpage.submit_new_account_form(
            {'first_name': 'Test', 'last_name': 'Test', 'phone_or_email':
              temp_email, 'newpass': '1q2w3e4r5t',
             'sex': 'male'})
```

I receive this error:

```
line 22, in test_new_account_succes
    'sex': 'male'})
TypeError: submit_new_account_form() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were       
given
```

Comment: Do you know what `**kwargs` means?

Comment: Please read my comment under Reti43's comment

Answer (score 6):

Well that is logical: `**credentials` means that you will provide it *named* arguments. But you do not provide a name for the dictionary.

There are two possibilities here:

1. you use `credentials` as a single argument, and pass it the dictionary, like:

   ```
   def submit_new_account_form(self, credentials):
       # ...
       pass

   loginpage.submit_new_account_form({'first_name': 'Test', 'last_name': 'Test', 'phone_or_email': temp_email, 'newpass': '1q2w3e4r5t', 'sex': 'male'})
   ```
2. you pass the dictionary as named arguments, by putting two asterisks in front:

   ```
   def submit_new_account_form(self, **credentials):
       # ...
       pass

   loginpage.submit_new_account_form(**{'first_name': 'Test', 'last_name': 'Test', 'phone_or_email': temp_email, 'newpass': '1q2w3e4r5t', 'sex': 'male'})
   ```

The second approach is equal to passing named arguments like:

```
loginpage.submit_new_account_form(first_name='Test', last_name='Test', phone_or_email=temp_email, newpass='1q2w3e4r5t', sex='male')
```

I think the last way to call this is cleaner syntax. Furthermore it allows you to easily modify the signature of the `submit_new_account_form` function signature to catch certain parameters immediately, instead of wrapping them into a dictionary.

Comment: I agree. The only time I would wrap the arguments in a dictionary if is they are settings to something that I intend to pass to functions multiple times, e.g., in `plt.plot()`

Comment: I will use this method in different automated testcases, in different cases(e.g. with or without arguments). Hence I decided to use such approach to put there optional arguments

Comment: @AkopAkopov: yes. Sure there can be circumstances like this one where it can be beneficial :). I'm only saying that this usually should ring a bell that perhaps you make things too complicated. That of course depends on the specific context :).